# get range of map elements with equal values

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, stl

I've got a map declared as:

```
std::map< std::pair<int, int>, bool > allPositions; // essentially, keys are just 2D points
```

I need to get the range of its elements whose values are `true`

Using `std::equal_range`

```
auto range = std::equal_range(allPositions.begin(), allPositions.end(), true);
```

Gives these errors

> Error C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded
>   function found xutility
>
> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type
>   std::less::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const' xutility
>
> Error C2056   illegal expression xutility
>
> Error C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded
>   function found algorithm
>
> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type
>   std::less::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const' algorithm

I think I don't need predicate function here because `std::pair` has got overloaded `operator <` otherwise map code wouldn't have been compiled

So how to use `std::equal_range` for map to get range of pairs with equal values ?

Comment: Regardless, I believe you still need a comparison function. Iterating through the map will give you key-value pairs, not just the values. And `true` is not by default comparable to `std::pair<std::pair<int,int>,bool>`.

Comment: use `map:equal_range` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range

Comment: @Altainia I know it gives pairs, I mean get range of map elements whose values are equal

Comment: You need different container for this, boost::multi_index for example, `std::map` will not give you range based on values.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the range of its elements whose **values** are `true`

You will have to iterate the the map to get the iterators whose value pair is `true`... I have a working example [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d00af354ddf90612). Something like this does the lifting.

```
template<typename Map,
         typename Value    = typename Map::mapped_type,
         typename Compare  = std::equal_to<Value>,
         typename Iterator = typename Map::iterator>
std::vector<Iterator> equal_values(const Map& mp, const Value& val, Compare cmp = Compare()){
    std::vector<Iterator> rtn;
    for(auto iter = mp.begin(); iter != mp.end(); ++iter)
        if(cmp(iter->second, val))
            rtn.push_back(iter);
    return rtn;
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to use [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) or [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Comment: this is not a solution  because 1st `std::map::equal_bound` takes a `key` as an argument but I need to get a range of pairs with same values, and 2nd simple iterating through a map would be inefficient, cause in this case I could just use vector instead of map to perform fast iterating which would be linear complexity but I need fast look up in logarithmic time

Comment: @ampawd With `std::map`, quick indexing and iteration is a one way journey (*key -> value*). Retrieving bounds via `keys` is a LogN thing. There is no way to retrieve bounds via `values` in LogN time. ... Making it logN in both directions isn't what `std::map` does. However, with a bit of work, you can juxtapose two maps to get that kind of behavior. THat's why I suggested Boost.Bimap

Answer (score 0):

> So how to use std::equal_range for map to get range of pairs with equal values ?

Let's say you have a map with following data:

```
{ {{0,0},false}, {{1,1},true}, {{2,2},false}, {{3,3},true} };
```

what you expect equal range to return for `true`? for `false`?

For that to work your container must be partitioned with respect to criteria you are using to get range. `std::map` is definitely not a such container for get range by value. So you would need to copy data or iterators into different container and sort it accordingly and use that container to get your ranges, or create  such container on the fly by filtering. Or you can use container like `boost::bimap` or `boost::multi_index` which can provide multiple indexes.

Answer (score -1):

So let's say you have a map as such:

```
using point = std::pair<int,int>;
std::map<point,bool> my_map;
```

And let's say you have some values in it as such:

```
my_map = { {{0,0},false}, {{0,1},true}, {{1,0},true}, {{1,1},false} };
```

Now let's see what the first iterator, when de-referenced, of this map will be:

```
{{0,0},false}
```

When you use `std::equal_range(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), true);` you're asking that `true` be checked to the de-referenced iterators. But the de-referenced iterator is not a boolean. It's a pair of a point and a boolean.
So what you may want to try is the following:

```
using map_iter = std::map<point,bool>::iterator; //is {point,bool}
auto range = std::equal_range(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), [](map_iter& iter){
  return iter.second == true;
};
```

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, this will address a compiler error but will not address the logical error of the values of the map not (necessarily) being sorted such that you can get a pair of iterators that define a range encompassing all of a matching value as a map is not sorted by value

Comment: For this to work data must be sorted by that criteria.

Comment: @Slava Yeah. This is true. I suppose this answer was meant more to address the misunderstanding that an iterator of a std::map does not dereference to the value alone.

Comment: Sorry, but then your answer is misleading. It may compile but you cannot use `std::range` with your lambda and such map.

Comment: Clarify? I do not see a point to provide fundamentally broken code to fix compilation error.